# Dart: Type safety for function that takes a function with varying return value as a parameter

Tags: dart, parametric-polymorphism

I am trying to create a Dart function that essentially wraps other functions with some boilerplate error handling code, and otherwise returns the value returned by the original function.  A key requirement is that it should accept functions with multiple different return types, while avoiding duplicating the common error handling logic across multiple different functions.  I found one approach that seems to work by using the dynamic type, except that the compiler is not able to detect type mismatches, so they are only caught at runtime.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm aiming for here, and particularly in a way that catches type mismatches at compile time?

Below is a simplified example of my code, where the functions compile fine, but at runtime getAString will raise an error  `Dart Error: Unhandled exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

/// Signature of API function calls
    typedef APIFunctionCall = dynamic Function();

```
dynamic doWithErrorHandling(APIFunctionCall fn, {retries: 2}) async {
  for (int attempts = 0; attempts < retries + 1; attempts++) {
    try {
      return await fn();
    }
    on Exception catch (e) {
      print(
          "This is just an example; actual function does a bunch of more specific error handling.");
    }
  }
}

Future<String> getAString() async {
  // Want a function that can support multiple return types but detect type errors
  String doesReturnAString =  await doWithErrorHandling(() async => 'hello world');  // This runs fine
  String doesntReturnAString = await doWithErrorHandling(() async => <String>['hello', 'world']);  // This throws an Error
  return doesntReturnAString;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can abstract over the return type using a type parameter:

```
Future<T> doWithErrorHandling<T>(Future<T> fn(), {int retries = 2}) async {
  do {
    try {
      return await fn();
    } catch (e) {
      // record error.
    }
    retries--;
  } while (retries >= 0);
  return null;  // or whatever.
}
```

With that, you can call with any function. In most cases, the type argument can be inferred from the static type of the argument function, or from the type expected by the surrounding context, but if not, you can write it yourself.

```
Future<String> getAString() async {
  String doesReturnAString =  await doWithErrorHandling(() async => 'hello world');  
  // The next line has a compile-time type error!
  String doesntReturnAString = await doWithErrorHandling(() async => <String>['hello', 'world']);
  return doesntReturnAString;
}
```

(As an unrelated hint, you should never catch `Exception`. Dart *errors* do not implement `Exception`, they implement `Error`. `Exception` is a meaningless marker interface used by some thrown objects that the user is intended to catch *and handle*, but in that case, you should be catching the particular exception, like `on FormatException`, not the plain `Exception`. So, general rule: Never write `on Exception`).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!  Do you know if there's any way to extend this to also support functions that take variable number and types arguments?  For example, in python I could say def f(g, *args, **kwargs): ....try: g(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Dart does not have varargs, and it doesn't have any function type that is a supertype of both a unary function and a binary function. With optional parameters, you can make one function that takes one or two arguments, `(a, [b]) { ...}`, but there is no single function type matching both `(a) {...}` and `(a, b) {...}`. There are not even optional type parameters, so a function type always has a specific number of type arguments. If you want to handle multiple different function signatures, I'd recommend having multiple helper functions, but that obviously doesn't scale to infinity.